# Does the nukeproof horizon mtb rim have a brake track?

Tags: rims, rim-brake

Does the nukeproof horizon mtb rim have a brake track? Can I use rim brakes with it?

https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/nukeproof-horizon-mtb-rim/rp-prod161912

Comment: The picture says no. They look like disc specific MTB rims.

Comment: If you zoom in on the picture it's obvious there is no rim brake track

Comment: That seller has a "submit question" option for each product, and the answers are displayed for future shoppers.  Consider asking there as well for a *definitive* answer and one that you could leverage into a return if they are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Zooming in on the image shows decals, stickers, appliques all the way to the edge of the rim. It also lacks a machined brake surface. So the appearance is that of a disc brake only wheel.